# Java SVG Salamander lineargradient not showing

Tags: java, svg, linear-gradients, svg-salamander

I am using SVG Salamander in an application, I've generated the SVG but when it is rendered the 'linearGradients' are not showing and the contents of the elements is just solid black.

If I take the SVG that is generated and open it in Firefox everything is correct and renders correctly.

SVG:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg id="root" style="background-color:#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="lamp1rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp1rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp1rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp1cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp1capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp1capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp1spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp1specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp1specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp2rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp2rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp2rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp2cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp2capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp2capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp2spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp2specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp2specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp3rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp3rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp3rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp3cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp3capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp3capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp3spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp3specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp3specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp4rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp4rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp4rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp4cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp4capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp4capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp4spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp4specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp4specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp5rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp5rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp5rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp5cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp5capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp5capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp5spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp5specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp5specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp6rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp6rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp6rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp6cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp6capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp6capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp6spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp6specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp6specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp7rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp7rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp7rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp7cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp7capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp7capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp7spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp7specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp7specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp8rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp8rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp8rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp8cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp8capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp8capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp8spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp8specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp8specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp9rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp9rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp9rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp9cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp9capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp9capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp9spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp9specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp9specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp10rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp10rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp10rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp10cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp10capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp10capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp10spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp10specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp10specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp11rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp11rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp11rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp11cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp11capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp11capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp11spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp11specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp11specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp12rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp12rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp12rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp12cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp12capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp12capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp12spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp12specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp12specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp13rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp13rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp13rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp13cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp13capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp13capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp13spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp13specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp13specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp14rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp14rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp14rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp14cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp14capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp14capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp14spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp14specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp14specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp15rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp15rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp15rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp15cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp15capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp15capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp15spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp15specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp15specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp16rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp16rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp16rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp16cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp16capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp16capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp16spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp16specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp16specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp17rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp17rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp17rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp17cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp17capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp17capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp17spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp17specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp17specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp18rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp18rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp18rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp18cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp18capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp18capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp18spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp18specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp18specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp19rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp19rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp19rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp19cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp19capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp19capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp19spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp19specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp19specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp20rim" y1="0" y2="0" x2="1" x1="0"><stop id="lamp20rimstp0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0"/><stop id="lamp20rimstp1" stop-color="#404040" offset="1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp20cap" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0"><stop id="lamp20capstp0" stop-color="#dd0000" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188"/><stop id="lamp20capstp1" stop-color="#820101" offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="lamp20spec" y1="0" y2="1" x2="1" spreadMethod="d" x1="0"><stop id="lamp20specstp0" stop-color="#ffffff" offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094"/><stop id="lamp20specstp1" stop-color="#d30606" offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375"/></linearGradient></defs><g id="lamp1" transform="translate(1204.0,0.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp1title">Lamp 1</title><circle id="lamp1shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp1outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp1lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp1highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp1label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 1</text></g><g id="lamp2" transform="translate(1302.0,0.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp2title">Lamp 2</title><circle id="lamp2shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp2outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp2lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp2highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp2label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 2</text></g><g id="lamp3" transform="translate(1204.0,98.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp3title">Lamp 3</title><circle id="lamp3shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp3outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp3lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp3highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp3label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 3</text></g><g id="lamp4" transform="translate(1302.0,98.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp4title">Lamp 4</title><circle id="lamp4shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp4outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp4rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp4lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp4cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp4highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp4spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp4label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 4</text></g><g id="lamp5" transform="translate(1204.0,196.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp5title">Lamp 5</title><circle id="lamp5shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp5outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp5rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp5lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp5cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp5highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp5spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp5label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 5</text></g><g id="lamp6" transform="translate(1302.0,196.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp6title">Lamp 6</title><circle id="lamp6shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp6outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp6rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp6lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp6cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp6highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp6spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp6label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 6</text></g><g id="lamp7" transform="translate(1204.0,294.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp7title">Lamp 7</title><circle id="lamp7shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp7outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp7rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp7lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp7cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp7highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp7spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp7label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 7</text></g><g id="lamp8" transform="translate(1302.0,294.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp8title">Lamp 8</title><circle id="lamp8shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp8outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp8rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp8lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp8cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp8highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp8spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp8label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 8</text></g><g id="lamp9" transform="translate(1204.0,392.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp9title">Lamp 9</title><circle id="lamp9shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp9outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp9rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp9lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp9cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp9highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp9spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp9label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 9</text></g><g id="lamp10" transform="translate(1302.0,392.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp10title">Lamp 10</title><circle id="lamp10shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp10outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp10rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp10lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp10cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp10highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp10spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp10label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 10</text></g><g id="lamp11" transform="translate(1204.0,490.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp11title">Lamp 11</title><circle id="lamp11shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp11outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp11rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp11lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp11cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp11highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp11spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp11label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 11</text></g><g id="lamp12" transform="translate(1302.0,490.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp12title">Lamp 12</title><circle id="lamp12shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp12outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp12rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp12lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp12cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp12highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp12spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp12label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 12</text></g><g id="lamp13" transform="translate(1204.0,686.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp13title">Lamp 13</title><circle id="lamp13shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp13outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp13rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp13lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp13cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp13highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp13spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp13label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 13</text></g><g id="lamp14" transform="translate(1302.0,686.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp14title">Lamp 14</title><circle id="lamp14shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp14outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp14rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp14lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp14cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp14highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp14spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp14label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 14</text></g><g id="lamp15" transform="translate(196.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp15title">Lamp 15</title><circle id="lamp15shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp15outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp15rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp15lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp15cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp15highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp15spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp15label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 15</text></g><g id="lamp16" transform="translate(294.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp16title">Lamp 16</title><circle id="lamp16shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp16outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp16rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp16lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp16cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp16highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp16spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp16label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 16</text></g><g id="lamp17" transform="translate(392.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp17title">Lamp 17</title><circle id="lamp17shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp17outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp17rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp17lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp17cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp17highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp17spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp17label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 17</text></g><g id="lamp18" transform="translate(490.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp18title">Lamp 18</title><circle id="lamp18shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp18outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp18rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp18lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp18cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp18highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp18spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp18label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 18</text></g><g id="lamp19" transform="translate(588.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp19title">Lamp 19</title><circle id="lamp19shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp19outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp19rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp19lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp19cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp19highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp19spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp19label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 19</text></g><g id="lamp20" transform="translate(686.0,952.0) scale(0.25)"><title id="lamp20title">Lamp 20</title><circle id="lamp20shroud" r="196" stroke-linecap="round" fill="#212121" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp20outline" r="180" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp20rim)" fill-opacity="0.64" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><circle id="lamp20lense" r="170" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp20cap)" cy="196" cx="196" stroke-width="1"/><ellipse id="lamp20highlight" transform="rotate(-40 260 150)" stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp20spec)" cy="40" cx="180" rx="85" stroke-width="1" ry="60"/><text id="lamp20label" font-size="44pt" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial Narrow" y="215" x="196">Lamp 20</text></g></svg>
```

Works fine when viewed in a browser:

https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPlatten/kcnz1sn5/1/

But not when SVG Salamander renders in Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

SVG Salamander requires the 'width' and 'height' attributes to be added to the 'svg' tag, once these were added rendering is then performed, without these attributes it shows as I have been experiencing, these are not required when rendered by a web browser.